# How to reload Container A after update Container B?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I have a ViewController containing a Segmented Control of 3 ContainerViews. Each Container is a ViewController containing a tableView. In CV2, I can choose a row. This row is deleted from CV2 and should be added in CV1.

Before use Segmented Controller, I used tab and table view on each tab were correctly updated. Now, with ContainerView, I don't know how to call the reload. This is my action on segment :

```
@IBAction func bSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
            self.listBOutlet.alpha = 1
            self.addBOutlet.alpha = 0
            self.delBOutlet.alpha = 0
        })
    } else {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
            self.listBOutlet.alpha = 0
            self.addBOutlet.alpha = 1
            self.delBOutlet.alpha = 0
        })
        } else {
            if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
                self.listBOutlet.alpha = 0
                self.addBOutlet.alpha = 0
                self.delBOutlet.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many things like this to access to viewWillAppear in CV2 :

```
            print(self.children)
            var myClass : ListeBEtb = self.????
            myClass.ListeB.reloadData()
            myClass.viewWillAppear(false)
```

But I don't know how to call ListeBEtb (CV1) to update it.

In my CV2 :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let recupListeBAddModel = RecupListeBAddModel()

    recupListeBAddModel.delegate = self

    recupListeBAddModel.downloadItems(id: idEtablissement)
    self.ListeB.reloadData()
}
```

Do you any idea about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ways of making this work, with the simplest one using the notification center for start.

Delegate pattern is the other, RxSwift is also an alternative, etc.

For using the notification center, first, define an extension for easier notification handling:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let rowDeleted = Notification.Name("rowDeleted")
}
```

After that, subscribe the the newly created notification in CV1:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rowDeleted), name: .rowDeleted, object: nil)
```

Note that you need a method called `rowDeleted` in CV1, or however you want to call it.

Also, make sure to remove yourself as an observer on deinit of CV1:

```
deinit { 
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Then, when you make an update in CV2, use something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .rowDeleted, object: nil)
```

This is all assuming you don't need to pass the actual object, but just need an event notification. Object passing is a bit different and better done with delegate pattern, but this is a decent start.

Comment: Ok, not sure to understand... So, the rowDeleted should be @objc func rowDeleted() {self.ListeB.reloadData()}. I have a "Ambiguous reference to member 'post(name:object:)'" on the notification in CV2. And, even if I don't enter in VC1  by func bSegment (my ibaction), the rowDeleted will execute ?

Comment: No, this works like any other pub/sub system, in order for your rowDeleted() method to trigger, there needs to be a notification posted first, since it's the subscription triggering it. Check the edit for a bit nicer handling that will fix your issues.

Comment: I managed to do what you said. It's running. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call some logic that exists in the `viewWillAppear(_:)` function, why not extract that into its own function, call that new function from `viewWillAppear(_:)`, and then you can call that function again when you transition your container views.

So in your container view, it would now look something like this.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    reloadDataModel()
}

func reloadDataModel() {
    let recupListeBAddModel = RecupListeBAddModel()

    recupListeBAddModel.delegate = self

    recupListeBAddModel.downloadItems(id: idEtablissement)
    self.ListeB.reloadData()
}
```

And then, in your transition code, perhaps just before your animation code, you can call `listBOutlet.reloadDataModel()`, so it can do the operation as the animation is in progress.

Comment: Thanks Josh... OK for your answer but my problem is how I call reloadDataModel() in the viewController because I never enter in ListeBEtb (CV1) once datas are displayed.

Comment: @MisterFisher I was assuming you stored a reference to your contained view controllers. So your parent view controller has a reference to the 3 view controllers you're presenting, and then you can call the method on the one you want to reload as you do the transition.